# Get The Last Google Form Update but only the selected Fields

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This Google App Script code returns all updates (Answers) of the form but I want to return only from selected fields out of many fields of the form.

E.g. I want to return only Name, Address, Mobile.

is it possible to do it GAS?

```
function getArrayOfLastSubmissionsAnswers() {
  var allQuestions,i,itemType,L,thisAnswer,thisQuestion,thisSubmissionsAnswers,number_of_submissions;
    //Define all variables without assigning a value - value at this point
    //is undefined

  number_of_submissions = FormApp.openById('1VH8ayeXPtsURs9MPxIJ9bj6wQVXmdD9yQ-JWHyOAZ8').getResponses().length;
  allQuestions = FormApp.openById('1VH8ayeXPtysURs9PxIJ9bj6wQVXmdD9yQ-JWHyOAZ8').getResponses()[number_of_submissions - 1].getItemResponses();

  L = allQuestions.length;//How many questions are there in the Form
  thisSubmissionsAnswers = [];//Create an empty array for answers

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {//Loop through all the questions in this Form submission
    thisQuestion = allQuestions[i];//Get this question

    itemType = thisQuestion.getItem().getType();

    if (itemType === FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK) {
      continue;//keep looping
    };

    thisAnswer = thisQuestion.getResponse();//Get the answer
    Logger.log(i + " - " + thisAnswer); 

    thisSubmissionsAnswers.push(thisAnswer);//add answer to the array
  };

  Logger.log("thisSubmissionsAnswers: " + thisSubmissionsAnswers); 

  return thisSubmissionsAnswers;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can used the method [getTitle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#gettitle) to retrieve the question text

Sample:

```js
...
thisQuestion = allQuestions[i];
var questionTitle = thisQuestion.getItem().getTitle();
console.log("question: " + questionTitle);
if(questionTitle == "Name" || questionTitle == "Address" || questionTitle == "Mobile"){
  ...
  thisAnswer = thisQuestion.getResponse();//Get the answer
  Logger.log(i + " - " + thisAnswer); 
  thisSubmissionsAnswers.push(thisAnswer);//add answer to the array
  ...
}
...
```